# ParseError: "ValidateError Field(s) `arch` failed : Invalid view definition Error details: Model not found: forecast.report

Tags: python, postgresql, localhost, odoo, odoo-8

I'm still debutant in developing specific modules in Odoo V8, I'm trying to install a module in Odoo 8, and i received the following error:

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 948, in call_button
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 447, in button_immediate_install
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 495, in _button_immediate_function
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 370, in new
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 355, in load_modules
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 255, in load_marked_modules
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 176, in load_module_graph
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 118, in _load_data
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 897, in convert_file
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 983, in convert_xml_import
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 849, in parse
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 759, in _tag_record
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_model.py", line 1069, in _update
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_ui_view.py", line 263, in create
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 372, in old_api
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 4101, in create
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 508, in new_api
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 4298, in _create
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20171010\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 1275, in _validate_fields
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) 'arch' failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Model not found: forecast.report

Error context:
View `forecast.report.graph`
[view_id: 871, xml_id: n/a, model: forecast.report, parent_id: n/a]" while parsing file:///c:/program%20files%20(x86)/odoo%208.0-20171010/server/openerp/addons/forecast_report/forecast_report_view.xml:5, near
<record id="view_order_product_graph" model="ir.ui.view">
         <field name="name">forecast.report.graph</field>
         <field name="model">forecast.report</field>
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
             <graph string="Sales Analysis" type="pivot" stacked="True">
                 <field name="section_id" type="row"/>
                 <field name="date" interval="month" type="col"/>
                 <field name="price_total" type="measure"/>
             </graph>
         </field>
    </record>
```

i created a module "Forecast Report" and i modified the code for generating a sale report,

Here is my code :

forecast_report.py :

```
from openerp import models, tools
from openerp.osv import fields, osv


class Forecast_report(models.Model):
    _name = "forecast_report"
    _description = "Forecast Statistics"
    _auto = False
    _rec_name = 'date'

    _columns = {
        'date': fields.datetime('Date Order', readonly=True),  # TDE FIXME master: rename into date_order
        'date_confirm': fields.date('Date Confirm', readonly=True),
        'product_id': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product', readonly=True),
        'product_uom': fields.many2one('product.uom', 'Unit of Measure', readonly=True),
        'product_uom_qty': fields.float('# of Qty', readonly=True),

        'partner_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Partner', readonly=True),
        'company_id': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Company', readonly=True),
        'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Salesperson', readonly=True),
        'price_total': fields.float('Total Price', readonly=True),
        'delay': fields.float('Commitment Delay', digits=(16,2), readonly=True),
        'categ_id': fields.many2one('product.category','Category of Product', readonly=True),
        'nbr': fields.integer('# of Lines', readonly=True),  # TDE FIXME master: rename into nbr_lines
        'state': fields.selection([
            ('cancel', 'Cancelled'),
            ('draft', 'Draft'),
            ('confirmed', 'Confirmed'),
            ('exception', 'Exception'),
            ('done', 'Done')], 'Order Status', readonly=True),
        'pricelist_id': fields.many2one('product.pricelist', 'Pricelist', readonly=True),
        'analytic_account_id': fields.many2one('account.analytic.account', 'Analytic Account', readonly=True),
        'section_id': fields.many2one('crm.case.section', 'Sales Team'),
    }
    _order = 'date desc'

    def _select(self):
        select_str = """
            WITH currency_rate (currency_id, rate, date_start, date_end) AS (
                    SELECT r.currency_id, r.rate, r.name AS date_start,
                        (SELECT name FROM res_currency_rate r2
                        WHERE r2.name > r.name AND
                            r2.currency_id = r.currency_id
                         ORDER BY r2.name ASC
                         LIMIT 1) AS date_end
                    FROM res_currency_rate r
                )
             SELECT min(l.id) as id,
                    l.product_id as product_id,
                    t.uom_id as product_uom,
                    sum(l.product_uom_qty / u.factor * u2.factor) as product_uom_qty,
                    sum(l.product_uom_qty * l.price_unit / cr.rate * (100.0-l.discount) / 100.0) as price_total,
                    count(*) as nbr,
                    s.date_order as date,
                    s.date_confirm as date_confirm,
                    s.partner_id as partner_id,
                    s.user_id as user_id,
                    s.company_id as company_id,
                    extract(epoch from avg(date_trunc('day',s.date_confirm)-date_trunc('day',s.create_date)))/(24*60*60)::decimal(16,2) as delay,
                    l.state,
                    t.categ_id as categ_id,
                    s.pricelist_id as pricelist_id,
                    s.project_id as analytic_account_id,
                    s.section_id as section_id
        """
        return select_str

    def _from(self):
        from_str = """
                sale_order_line l
                      join sale_order s on (l.order_id=s.id)
                        left join product_product p on (l.product_id=p.id)
                            left join product_template t on (p.product_tmpl_id=t.id)
                    left join product_uom u on (u.id=l.product_uom)
                    left join product_uom u2 on (u2.id=t.uom_id)
                    left join product_pricelist pp on (s.pricelist_id = pp.id)
                    join currency_rate cr on (cr.currency_id = pp.currency_id and
                        cr.date_start <= coalesce(s.date_order, now()) and
                        (cr.date_end is null or cr.date_end > coalesce(s.date_order, now())))
        """
        return from_str

    def _group_by(self):
        group_by_str = """
            GROUP BY l.product_id,
                    l.order_id,
                    t.uom_id,
                    t.categ_id,
                    s.date_order,
                    s.date_confirm,
                    s.partner_id,
                    s.user_id,
                    s.company_id,
                    l.state,
                    s.pricelist_id,
                    s.project_id,
                    s.section_id
        """
        return group_by_str

    def init(self, cr):
        # self._table = sale_report
        tools.drop_view_if_exists(cr, self._table)
        cr.execute("""CREATE or REPLACE VIEW %s as (
            %s
            FROM ( %s )
            %s
            )""" % (self._table, self._select(), self._from(), self._group_by()))
```

forecast_report_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>

    <record id="view_order_product_graph" model="ir.ui.view">
         <field name="name">forecast.report.graph</field>
         <field name="model">forecast.report</field>
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
             <graph string="Sales Analysis" type="pivot" stacked="True">
                 <field name="section_id" type="row"/>
                 <field name="date" interval="month" type="col"/>
                 <field name="price_total" type="measure"/>
             </graph>
         </field>
    </record>

    <!-- Custom reports (aka filters) -->
    <record id="filter_sale_report_sales_funnel" model="ir.filters">
        <field name="name">Sales Funnel</field>
        <field name="model_id">forecast.report</field>
        <field name="domain">['&amp;', ('date','&lt;=', time.strftime('%%Y-12-31')), '&amp;', ('date','&gt;=',time.strftime('%%Y-01-01')), ('state','not in',('cancel',))]</field>
        <field name="user_id" eval="False"/>
        <field name="context">{'group_by': ['state'], 'measures': ['price_total']}</field>
    </record>
    <record id="filter_sale_report_salespersons" model="ir.filters">
        <field name="name">By Salespersons</field>
        <field name="model_id">forecast.report</field>
        <field name="user_id" eval="False"/>
        <field name="context">{'group_by': ['date:month', 'user_id']}</field>
    </record>
    <record id="filter_sale_report_salesteam" model="ir.filters">
        <field name="name">By Salesteam</field>
        <field name="model_id">forecast.report</field>
        <field name="user_id" eval="False"/>
        <field name="context">{'group_by': ['date:month', 'section_id']}</field>
    </record>
    <record id="filter_isale_report_product" model="ir.filters">
        <field name="name">By Product</field>
        <field name="model_id">forecast.report</field>
        <field name="user_id" eval="False"/>
        <field name="context">{'group_by': ['date:month', 'product_id']}</field>
    </record>

    <record id="view_order_product_search" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">forecast.report.search</field>
        <field name="model">forecast.report</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Sales Analysis">
                <field name="date"/>
                <field name="date_confirm"/>
                <filter string="This Year" name="year" invisible="1" domain="[('date','&lt;=', time.strftime('%%Y-12-31')),('date','&gt;=',time.strftime('%%Y-01-01'))]"/>
                <filter name="Quotations" string="Quotations" domain="[('state','=','draft')]"/>
                <filter name="Sales" string="Sales" domain="[('state','not in',('draft', 'cancel'))]"/>
                <separator/>
                <filter string="My Sales" help="My Sales" domain="[('user_id','=',uid)]"/>
                <field name="partner_id"/>
                <field name="product_id"/>
                <field name="user_id"/>
                <group expand="0" string="Extended Filters">
                    <field name="categ_id" filter_domain="[('categ_id', 'child_of', self)]"/>
                    <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company"/>
                </group>
                <group expand="1" string="Group By">
                    <filter string="Salesperson" name="User" context="{'group_by':'user_id'}"/>
                    <filter string="Sales Team" context="{'group_by':'section_id'}" groups="base.group_multi_salesteams"/>
                    <filter string="Customer" name="Customer" context="{'group_by':'partner_id'}"/>
                    <filter string="Category of Product" name="Category" context="{'group_by':'categ_id'}"/>
                    <filter string="Status" context="{'group_by':'state'}"/>
                    <filter string="Company" groups="base.group_multi_company" context="{'group_by':'company_id'}"/>
                    <separator/>
                    <filter string="Order Month" context="{'group_by':'date:month'}" help="Ordered date of the sales order"/>
                </group>
            </search>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="action_order_report_all" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Forecast Analysis</field>
        <field name="res_model">forecast.report</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">graph</field>
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_order_product_search"/>
        <field name="view_id" ref="view_order_product_graph"/>
        <field name="context">{'search_default_Sales':1, 'group_by_no_leaf':1,'group_by':[]}</field>
        <field name="help">This report performs analysis on your quotations and sales orders. Analysis check your sales revenues and sort it by different group criteria (salesman, partner, product, etc.) Use this report to perform analysis on sales not having invoiced yet. If you want to analyse your turnover, you should use the Invoice Analysis report in the Accounting application.</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem action="action_order_report_all" id="menu_report_product_all" parent="base.next_id_64" sequence="10"/>

</data>
</openerp>
```

forecast_report.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <report 
            id="forecast_sale_order"
            string="Sales Forecasts / Sales Forecast Lines"
            model="sale.order" 
            report_type="qweb-pdf"
            file="forecast_report.report_saleorder" 
            name="forecast_report.report_saleorder" 
        />
    </data>
</openerp>
```

I expect the results of sales analysis in Odoo 8 (similar to the basic one), but with  different model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is called `forecase_report` because you've defined it that way in `_name = "forecast_report"`. So either change the model name in every depending file or change the `_name` to odoo's guideline style `forecast.report`.

Comment: Yes you're right, I changed the `_name` to `forecast.report` , but that did not solved the problem :( , i think there is a fail in the `forecast_report_view.xml` in the graph

Answer (score 0):

Please change `_name = "forecast.report".`
Restart and upgrade module.